# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin^2(n)}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Does the series $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin^2(n)}{n} $$
>   converge?

I've tried to apply some tests, and I don't know how to bound the general term, so I must have missed something. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not asking this on the page of your previous question?

Comment: @did Now I can't delete this question. I'm sorry. Thanks for this example.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Hint:

Each interval of the form $\bigl[k\pi+{\pi\over6}, (k+1)\pi-{\pi\over6}\bigr)$ contains an integer $n_k$. We then have, for each $k$, that ${\sin^2(n_k)\over n_k}\ge {(1/2)^2\over (k+1)\pi}$. Now use a comparison test to show your series diverges.

Comment: How could you prove that in every interval $\bigl[k\pi+{\pi\over6}, (k+1)\pi-{\pi\over6}\bigr)$ has an integer $n_k$?

Comment: @ZackNi The length of such an interval is $\pi-\pi/3>1$.

Answer (score 6):

It is divergent:

Write
$$\sum \frac{\sin^2(n)}{n} = 
\sum \frac{1}{2n} - \sum \frac{\cos(2n)}{2n},$$
clearly at the right handed side, the first is divergent but the second converges.