# Convergence of $\sum_n^\infty (-1)^n\frac{\sin^2 n}n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, convergence-divergence

Could anyone give a hint how to prove the convergence of the following sum?

$$\sum_n^\infty (-1)^n\frac{\sin^2 n}n$$

I tried writing it like this instead:

$$\sum_n^\infty \frac1n (-1)^n \sin^2 n.$$

From here, it is easy to see that $\frac1n$ is a bounded and strictly decreasing sequence. It would be sufficient to prove that the sequence of partial sums of $(-1)^n\sin^2 n$ is bounded.

From here, I get that $(-1)^n\sin^2 n = (-1)^n\frac{1 - \cos 2n}2 = \frac{(-1)^n}2 - \frac{(-1)^n \cos2n}2$, where the sequence of partial sums of $\frac{(-1)^n}2$ is bounded as well as the sequence of partial sums of $\frac{\cos 2n}2$. Unfortunately, I cannot tell anything about $\frac{(-1)^n\cos 2n}2$.

Thank you.

Comment: somewhat related to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/273559/convergence-of-sum-n-1-infty-frac-sin2nn?rq=1

Comment: Thanks. I know this proof, but I will have a look at it again.

Comment: Why not use [Leibnitz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_criterion) and
$$0 \leq \frac{\sin^2 n}{n} \leq \frac{1}{n}$$
??

Comment: @AlexR You'd have to have that $\frac{\sin^2 n}n$ is a *monotonic* sequence, and you do not have that. At least I know Leibniz's theorem like this.

Comment: Use it on $\frac{1}{n}$ and combine with comparison ;)

Comment: @Shobhit Thank you for the link! I have known a different proof of the same thing, but this one is more fun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The series [is not absolutely convergent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/273559/convergence-of-sum-n-1-infty-frac-sin2nn?rq=1), so the study of convergence is of interest.

We have 
$$\sin^2n=1-\cos^2n=1-\frac{1+\cos(2n)}2=\frac 12-\frac{\cos(2n)}2.$$
Since $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}n\mbox{ is  convergent},$$
we only have to address the convergence of $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{\cos(2n)}n,$$
which can be done by a summation by parts. Indeed, we define $s_n:=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k$. Then 
$$\sum_{k=M}^N(-1)^k\frac{\cos(2k)}k=\sum_{n=M}^Ns_n\frac{\cos(2n)}n-\sum_{n=M-1}^{N-1}s_n\frac{\cos(2(n+1))}{n+1}.$$
Since the series $\sum_k\frac 1{k^2}$ is convergent, we actually only have to show that the series 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty s_n\frac{\cos(2n)}{n}\mbox{ and }\sum_{n=1}^\infty s_n\frac{\cos(2(n+1))}{n}$$
are convergent. (Indeed, $\frac{\cos(2n)}n-\frac{\cos(2(n+1))}{n+1}=\frac{\cos(2n)-\cos(2(n+1))}n-\cos(2(n+1))\left(\frac 1n-\frac 1{n+1}\right) $.) Since $s_{2k+1}=0$, it's enough to establish the convergence of 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(4n)}n\mbox{ and }\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(2(2n+1))}n.$$
It can be done by (an other!) summation by parts.

Comment: I set $a_n = \frac1n$ and $b_n = (-1)^n\cos(2n)$, but I do not see how do I match this onto $\sum_{k=m}^n a_k(b_{k+1} - b_k)$.

Comment: @DavidČepelík I've added details.

Comment: I have means of proving that the last two sums are convergent, so I could get away with just one summation by parts. But I do get a little lost where you talk about $\sum_k \frac1{k^2}$. Where does it come from?

Comment: I've edited. Is it clearer?

Comment: How would you prove that the last two sums converge. That seems like the difficult part

Comment: Can't we use the fact that $|\sum_{k=1}^N\cos(4k)|$ is bounded, the same for $\sin$?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo: ah, yes, that works. You need to know that $\pi$ is irrational for that (essentially, the same thing as using equidistribution) but it gives convergence.

Comment: Actually, I was wrong there, you don't need to know that $\pi$ is rational. Just writing in terms of complex exponentials and using the formula for summing geometric series works fine on its own.

Answer (score 3):

We will use Dirichlet's test: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test

Write $\frac 1 n (-1)^n\sin(n)^2 = \frac 1 n  (-1)^{n+1} \frac{e^{2in}-2+e^{-2in}}{4}$, which follows from Euler's formulas.

Our series naturally splits in a sum of $3$ series. Set $a_n = \frac 1 n$. Set $b_n =(-1)^{n+1} \frac{e^{2in}}{4}$. Then $\sum_{n=1}^M b_n $ is a geometric sum, with quotient $-e^{2i}$, that can be evaluated as $\frac{e^{2i}}{4} \frac{(-1)^M e^{2iM}-1}{-e^{2i}-1}$. We see that $|\sum_{n=1}^M b_n|<2$ for all $M$. By Dirichlet's test $\sum a_n b_n$ converges. The remaining two series can be handled similarly.

Comment: Hold a minute, please; it's $\sin^2 n = (\sin n)^2$, not $\sin n^2$. Or is it a typo?

Comment: I got lazy for the $\frac{1}{n}$-Terms, but that suffices for the convergence part =)

Comment: @David, I meant to use $(\sin n)^2$ in my answer. That is what I mean by $\sin(n)^2$. (Note that parentheses.)

Comment: But how do you show that the absolute value of the sum is lower than 2?

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT**
$$- \log(1+e^{\pm 2i}) =\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} (-1)^n \frac{e^{\pm 2i n}}{n}$$
And
$$\sin^2 n = -\frac{1}{4} (e^{in} - e^{-in})^2 = - \frac{1}{4} (e^{2in} - 2 + e^{-2in}) = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{4} (e^{2in} + e^{-2in})$$
So with $\Sigma$ for the "target sum":
$$\Sigma = \frac{1}{2} \underbrace{\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} (-1)^n \frac{1}{n}}_{=-\log(2)} - \frac{1}{4} \underbrace{\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} (-1)^n\frac{e^{2in}}{n}}_{= -\log(1+e^{2in})} - \frac{1}{4} \underbrace{\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} (-1)^n \frac{e^{-2in}}{n}}_{=-\log(1+e^{-2in})} = \frac{1}{4} (-\log(4) + \log(1+e^{2i}) + \log(1+e^{-2i}))$$

Comment: only positive series will work

Comment: I do not think you can use comparison test; the terms of the sequence are not positive.

Comment: Okay, but I think you can still get the same convergence behaviour somehow... I see that $a_n = \frac{1}{n} \chi_{\{2\mathbb{N}\}}$ provides a counter-example.
I'll look into it. Thanks for the remark.

Comment: Approximating the value of the $n$-th term as $n \to \infty$ won't probably work either; you are summing a (very small) error infinitely many times; hence you can get different results.

Comment: I removed the false portion to avoid irritations.

Comment: I am sorry, what is WIA?

Comment: I see - W|A - WolframAlpha. Thought it's Windows Image Acquisition, looked really strange in the context of a math post :).

Comment: @DavidČepelík Is that okay?

Comment: @AlexR Thanks for your answer. I would like to wait a little longer. Maybe another proof will arise that is simpler. Unfortunately, I haven't had my complex analysis class yet, so my understanding of this proof is somewhat limited. But from what I can comprehend, I think it is correct this way.

Comment: Actually, the argument seems a bit circular: you used the expression given in the first equation, but I'm not sure proving the convergence of the series in the RHS is simpler than proving those of the OP.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo I use the Series expansion of the logarithm, yes, but that and eulers' identity for sine is all I use here. I don't see any "circular" proof...

Comment: You have to prove that the series expansion of the logarithm is convergent in this part of boundary of the disk of convergence, which is not easier than the proof of the convergence of $\sum_n(-1)^n\frac{\sin n}n$. (what I mean is that it deserves some details)

Comment: Well, from my point of view, the series expansion of the Logarithm is somewhat "basic knowledge". If you don't allow this Identity, then you need to find another proof (for example yours) ;)

Answer (score -2):

Using Alternative convergence theorem.
As long As $b_n$ has limit when $n$ approaches infinity, and the limit equals to $0$,
the serise $a_n=(-1)^n b_n$ is convergence.

Comment: Could you please support this statement with a link to a page describing the theorem you are using?

Comment: @DavidČepelík [Alternating Series Test](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/AlternatingSeries.aspx)    [CONVERGENCE AND DIVERGENCE OF INFINITE SERIES](http://www.math.washington.edu/~greenber/MATH327-InfSeries.pdf)

Comment: Unfortunately, you still need to have that $b_n$ is a *nonincreasing* sequence; and you do not have that as neither $(-1)^n$ nor $\frac{sin^2 n}n$ are monotone. (If you let $b_n := \frac1n$ for $n$ even and zero otherwise, it would not work, for example. The limit would be zero, obviously, but the sum would not converge.) Thanks for help anyway.

Comment: see the second one.

Comment: I have seen both.