# Suppose $\sum{a_n}$ converges. Either prove that $\sum{b_n}$ converges or give a counter-example

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose $\sum{a_n}$ is a convergent series of real numbers. Either prove that $\sum{b_n}$ converges or give a counter-example, when we define $b_n$ by:

1. $a_n \sin(n)$
2. $n^{\frac{1}{n}}a_n$

For the first one, I was thinking of using the fact that $|\sin(n)| \leq 1$ and then using comparison test. However, we don't know that $\sum{|a_n|}$ converges.

For the second one, I was thinking of using the fact that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} n^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$. But, I'm completely stuck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For 1), take $a_n = \dfrac{\sin n}{n}$. Then $\sum a_n$ converges (by Dirichlet's test), but
$$ \sum \frac{\sin^2 n}{n} $$
diverges, see [Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin^2(n)}{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/273559).

For 2), the series $\sum b_n$ converges by [Abel's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_test)

Comment: Could you please just sketch how to use Abel's test? I don't see how it applies here.

Comment: @AlexM. $(n^{1/n})$ is monotone (for $n \ge 3$) and bounded. (Maybe you're thinking of the "other" Abel's test for power series. The terminology seems to be a little non-standardized.)

Comment: I hadn't checked your link and I had a different statement in mind.

Comment: @AlexM. Thank you so much! I wanted to use Abel's test on the second one, but I didn't realize you can throw out the first n terms that make the sequence not monotone as long as after those n terms the sequence is monotone (is that the correct way of thinking)?

Comment: @jwise: Yes, that is correct, but I think that you wanted to talk to Mrf, not to me.