# Is there an easy way to prove that this series diverges?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Consider the series

$$\sum_{n}\dfrac{1-\cos(2n\theta_0)}{2n},$$

where $0<\theta_0<\pi$. Is there one easy way to prove that it diverges? I wanted to used this to prove that the series $\sum_n \frac{\sin|n\theta_0|}{n}$ diverges, so comparing with this series wouldn't be an option here.

I tried the ratio test, but didn'g get far, I needed to evaluate the limit

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{1-\cos(2(n+1)\theta_0)}{2(n+1)}\dfrac{2n}{1-\cos(2n\theta_0)},$$

but this also seems complicated. Is there one easier way to show that this series diverges? How can I prove this?

Comment: with Abel: divergent$-$ convergent$=$divergent.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam Does $$\sum_n \frac{cos(2n\theta_0)}{2n}$$ actually converge ? A moment ... Do you mean the corresponding improper integral ?

Comment: This series actually converges as its similar to the alternating harmonic series, essentially $\sin(|n\theta_0|) "=" (-1)^n$ (more or less). The alternating series test will show that it converges.

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro

Comment: @Peter Yes, by Abel's rule, like the improper integral.

Comment: Does this answer your question [use $\sin^2(t)=1/2(1-\cos(2t))$]? [Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin^2(n)}{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/273559/convergence-of-sum-n-1-infty-frac-sin2nn)